# Horizontal alignment of a bunch of verses

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like to horizontally align a few verses in the center of the page (i.e. the first letter of each verse should appear on the same column).

My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\newenvironment{myverse}
{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{l}}
{\end{tabular}\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myverse}
vakṣomandiramattahastigamanānāthāṅghripadmadvaye\\
sarvāpannagabhedinaikakuliśe saṃpatsarojāruṇe~.\\
devendrādikirīṭaratnakiraṇaprāgbhāranīrājite  \\
śrīmannaiṣadhakāvyaratnasaralavyākhyāsmadīyārpyate  ..\\
\end{myverse}

\begin{myverse}
śākhādīrghakarāgrabhāsuramanohāriprasūnavrajaiḥ\\
śākhāsusthitagānaśauṇḍapikarāṭsaṃdohasatkūjitaiḥ~. \\
vīthīpārśvasarittaṭādritaravo'pyarcanti yaṃ sarvadā   \\
śrīpatyākhyapure tadīyapadayorvyākhyāsmadīyārpyate   ..\\
\end{myverse}
  
\begin{myverse}
śrīśeṣācalasānusaudhavilasaddevādhidevaprabhoḥ\\
vidyuddvandvaniṣevyamāṇajaladaspardhisphuradvarṣmaṇaḥ~. \\
snānācāmavalokamātranihatāghaughāpagājanmada-   \\
śrīpādasya padāmbujātayugale vyākhyāsmadīyārpyate ..\\
\end{myverse}
  
\begin{myverse}
ete yasya kṛpākaṭākṣanikaṭaprānte vasantīti taiḥ\\
īrṣyānirbharaphullaromanikarairbobhūyyate nirjaraiḥ~. \\
śrīpatyākhyapurīvihārisujanānālokya vidhyādibhiḥ \\
tatpādābmuruhadvayāntikatale vyākhyāsmadīyārpyate  ..\\
\end{myverse}

\begin{myverse}
kanyāṃ “bālaramāṃ” gṛhāṇa sumukhīṃ svacchānvayenāñcitām \\
harṣaślokasamanvitāṃ pratipadaṃ sārthāṃ ca bhāvānvitām ~. \\
mādhuryeṇa yutāṃ suvarṇakalitāṃ sadbhaktisaṃśobhitāṃ \\
kāruṇyāmṛta! vārṣukābda! dayayā śrīveṅkaṭeśa! prabho!  ..\\
\end{myverse}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

I tried enclosing these verses in a tabular environment but that didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\newenvironment{myverse}
{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{l}}
{\end{tabular}\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myverse}
vakṣomandiramattahastigamanānāthāṅghripadmadvaye\\
sarvāpannagabhedinaikakuliśe saṃpatsarojāruṇe~.\\
devendrādikirīṭaratnakiraṇaprāgbhāranīrājite  \\
śrīmannaiṣadhakāvyaratnasaralavyākhyāsmadīyārpyate  ..\\
%\end{myverse}
\\
%\begin{myverse}
śākhādīrghakarāgrabhāsuramanohāriprasūnavrajaiḥ\\
śākhāsusthitagānaśauṇḍapikarāṭsaṃdohasatkūjitaiḥ~. \\
vīthīpārśvasarittaṭādritaravo'pyarcanti yaṃ sarvadā   \\
śrīpatyākhyapure tadīyapadayorvyākhyāsmadīyārpyate   ..\\
%\end{myverse}
\\
%\begin{myverse}
śrīśeṣācalasānusaudhavilasaddevādhidevaprabhoḥ\\
vidyuddvandvaniṣevyamāṇajaladaspardhisphuradvarṣmaṇaḥ~. \\
snānācāmavalokamātranihatāghaughāpagājanmada-   \\
śrīpādasya padāmbujātayugale vyākhyāsmadīyārpyate ..\\
%\end{myverse}
\\ 
%\begin{myverse}
ete yasya kṛpākaṭākṣanikaṭaprānte vasantīti taiḥ\\
īrṣyānirbharaphullaromanikarairbobhūyyate nirjaraiḥ~. \\
śrīpatyākhyapurīvihārisujanānālokya vidhyādibhiḥ \\
tatpādābmuruhadvayāntikatale vyākhyāsmadīyārpyate  ..\\
%\end{myverse}
\\
%\begin{myverse}
kanyāṃ “bālaramāṃ” gṛhāṇa sumukhīṃ svacchānvayenāñcitām \\
harṣaślokasamanvitāṃ pratipadaṃ sārthāṃ ca bhāvānvitām ~. \\
mādhuryeṇa yutāṃ suvarṇakalitāṃ sadbhaktisaṃśobhitāṃ \\
kāruṇyāmṛta! vārṣukābda! dayayā śrīveṅkaṭeśa! prabho!  ..\\
\end{myverse}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with the standard `verse` environment? Or, if you want more tweaks try the `verse` package.

```
% verseprob.tex  SE 603221
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newenvironment{myverse}
{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{l}}
{\end{tabular}\end{center}}

\begin{document}

%\begin{myverse}
\begin{verse}
vakṣomandiramattahastigamanānāthāṅghripadmadvaye\\
sarvāpannagabhedinaikakuliśe saṃpatsarojāruṇe~.\\
devendrādikirīṭaratnakiraṇaprāgbhāranīrājite  \\
śrīmannaiṣadhakāvyaratnasaralavyākhyāsmadīyārpyate  ..\\
\end{verse}
%\end{myverse}

%\begin{myverse}
\begin{verse}ś
ākhādīrghakarāgrabhāsuramanohāriprasūnavrajaiḥ\\
śākhāsusthitagānaśauṇḍapikarāṭsaṃdohasatkūjitaiḥ~. \\
vīthīpārśvasarittaṭādritaravo'pyarcanti yaṃ sarvadā   \\
śrīpatyākhyapure tadīyapadayorvyākhyāsmadīyārpyate   ..\\
\end{verse}
%\end{myverse}
  
%\begin{myverse}
\begin{verse}
śrīśeṣācalasānusaudhavilasaddevādhidevaprabhoḥ\\
vidyuddvandvaniṣevyamāṇajaladaspardhisphuradvarṣmaṇaḥ~. \\
snānācāmavalokamātranihatāghaughāpagājanmada-   \\
śrīpādasya padāmbujātayugale vyākhyāsmadīyārpyate ..\\
\end{verse}
%\end{myverse}
  
%\begin{myverse}
\begin{verse}
ete yasya kṛpākaṭākṣanikaṭaprānte vasantīti taiḥ\\
īrṣyānirbharaphullaromanikarairbobhūyyate nirjaraiḥ~. \\
śrīpatyākhyapurīvihārisujanānālokya vidhyādibhiḥ \\
tatpādābmuruhadvayāntikatale vyākhyāsmadīyārpyate  ..\\
\end{verse}
%\end{myverse}

%\begin{myverse}
\begin{verse}
kanyāṃ “bālaramāṃ” gṛhāṇa sumukhīṃ svacchānvayenāñcitām \\
harṣaślokasamanvitāṃ pratipadaṃ sārthāṃ ca bhāvānvitām ~. \\
mādhuryeṇa yutāṃ suvarṇakalitāṃ sadbhaktisaṃśobhitāṃ \\
kāruṇyāmṛta! vārṣukābda! dayayā śrīveṅkaṭeśa! prabho!  ..\\
\end{verse}
%\end{myverse}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]